# Submit & Recall Approval Request Button Missing On Custom Related List

Tags: visualforce, approval-process, related-list

I have custom `Visualforce Page` which included the approval process as related list.

```
<apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps"/>
```

I can't see <kbd>Submit</kbd> & <kbd>Recall</kbd> Approval Request button even I'm a system administrator.

[image: Related List Screenshot]

Comment: Is this button available on the Original Page Layout's Related List? If not please add it then check.

Comment: Both button are available for Non Override

Comment: I am not able to see any button.